# PostgreSQL Query Time

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

```
SELECT * 
FROM vehicles t1 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vehicles t2
       WHERE  t1.pump_number = t2.pump_number
          AND t1.updated_at < t2.updated_at
      ) < 4
      AND t1.updated_at >= ?
```

And I supply `'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000'` for the parameter `?`.

I have around 10k records in the `vehicles` table and no index is added. Above query takes around 10-20 seconds in execution.

How I can optimize it to decrease execution time?

Comment: I just corrected title

Comment: Do you want the predicate `t1.updated_at >= ?` to apply to the count in the subquery as well? Because it doesn't as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres provide nice admin tool which has option EXPLAIN  to see query execution plan .
 It will give great insights . here is the link for pgadmin in detail 
http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/query.html

Also use joins in your query instead of select that will increase your  query performance

Answer (score 0):

Try this( the columns in select and group by statement need to be replaced by your own):

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.updated_at,
    t1.other_columns
FROM vehicles t1 
INNER JOIN vehicles t2
ON  t1.pump_number = t2.pump_number
    AND t1.updated_at < t2.updated_at
WHERE t1.updated_at >= '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000'
GROUP BY 
    t1.id,
    t1.updated_at,
    t1.other_columns
having count(*)< 4
```

After this change, you could try to add a index on column pump_number to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM vehicles t1
WHERE  (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM vehicles t2
        WHERE t1.pump_number = t2.pump_number AND
              t1.updated_at < t2.updated_at
       ) < 4  AND
       t1.updated_at >= ? " , "1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000")]
```

I would start by writing this using window functions:

```
select v.*
from (select v.*, row_number() over (partition by pump_number order by updated_at) as seqnum
      from vehicles v
     ) v
where v.seqnum < 4 and t1.updated_at >= ?;
```

For this query, I would suggest indexes on `vehicles(pump_number, updted_at)` and `vehicles(updated_at)`.

Answer (score 0):

To get an equivalent query, use the window function **[`rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html)**, not <strike>`row_number()`</strike> here:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY pump_number ORDER BY updated_at DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   vehicles t1 
   ) sub
WHERE rnk < 4
AND   updated_at >= '1970-01-01 0:0';
```

And it has to be `ORDER BY updated_at DESC`, to exclude rows that have more than three *older* peers for the same `pump_number`. In other words:
*"Get the three oldest rows per `pump_number` - or more if there are ties on `updated_at`"*.

Indexes are not going to help while you read most or all of the table anyway.

#### Further optimize performance

If `(pump_number, updated_at)` is unique or / and there are relatively few distinct values for `pump_number` in `vehicles`, you can probably optimize further. There is not enough information in your question.